# Date filter for logstash seems to change date to older value

Tags: elastic-stack

I am parsing logs in the format

```
2017-04-03 05:48:16,129....
```

I am parsing this using grok as

```
match => {"message" => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp},.*\|%{DATA:logLevel}\|.*\|.*\|.*\|.*\|.*\|%{DATA:service}\|.*\|.*\|.*\|%{DATA:successMsg} :%{USERNAME:loginUser}"}
```

After this I am applying date filter to get timestamp value as -

```
date {
                            match => [ "timestamp", "yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss" ]
                            target => "timestamp"
                        }
```

The value I receive in elastic is offset by 3 months.
ie - **2017-04-03 05:48:16** is coverted to **January 3rd 2017, 05:48:16**

All other fields are fine. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer somewhere else.
https://discuss.elastic.co/t/date-filter-for-logstash-seems-to-change-date-to-older-value/80983

It's only that the month should be MM and not mm. Not sure how this led to the behavior though.